# No aux file created

Tags: biblatex, auxiliary-files

I wrote my master thesis on a different computer and now I want to compile using TexWorks (with `pdflatex`+`makeindex`+`bibtex`) as I did on the other PC.

On the new PC no `.aux` files are created (in the subfolders) and only the bibliography has disappeared. Citations are only given as **[name in `.bib` file]**.
Has this ever happened to someone before. Do you have any answer to this?
I provide a minimal example. My `main.tex` file lokks like this:

```
% kate: encoding iso-8859-1
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % Improves appearance of some cm-super fonts
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}    % warns about some obsolete latex  constructs
\documentclass[
12pt,                % font size 12pt
a4paper,             % layout for DIN A4
twoside,             % layout for one sided printing
headinclude,         % include head in layout computation
headsepline,         % horizontal line below head
BCOR20mm,            % correction for fixation
DIV16,               % DIV-value for creating the print space, (see scrguien.pdf)
halfparskip,         % spacing between paragraphs
openany,             % chapters may start on even and odd pages
bibtotoc,            % put bibliography into table of contents
pointlessnumbers,    % chapter numbers without full stop
tablecaptionabove,   % use table headings with correct spacing
]{scrbook}[2007/12/24]  % scrbook-Version min. v2.98 from 2007/12/24

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    % change to your encoding (e.g. utf8)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % correct pdf output (correct umlaut charaters)
%\usepackage{lmodern}             % fonts for pdf-file creation (use Type1 instead of Type3) - only needed, if cmsuper is not installed
%                                 % check the resulting pdf-file: fonts should been embedded, subsetted and of type 1 (NOT type 3!)
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}  % place the subscripts and superscripts in the right position
\usepackage{amsfonts}            % additional fonts like \mathbb, \mathfrak
\usepackage{amssymb}             % additional symbols
\usepackage{bbm}                 % indicator function
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{url}                 % support for urls
\usepackage[ style = alphabetic, natbib = true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage[english]{babel}             % English orthography
\usepackage{scrpage2}            % head and foot layout
\usepackage{ushort}              % complex values require an underline (use\ushort or \ushortw)
\usepackage{units}               % package for setting units in a typographically correct way (e.g. \unit[3]{cm})
\usepackage{booktabs}            % package provides additional commands to enhance the quality of tables
\usepackage{datetime}            % provides \pdfdate command
\usepackage[pageno, draft]{listofsymbols}   % includes a lis of symbols/ good to have an overview over one's notations
\usepackage{verbatim}   % use multiline comments
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{subfig}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % amsmath: numbering equations
\addbibresource{main}
\bibliography{main}                             % read file main.bib   (bibliography entries)
\usepackage{csquotes}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}          % enable scrheadings layout for head and foot

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
% non pdflatex settings (normal latex compiler assumed)
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
% different settings for the pdflatex compiler
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}           % enables automatic conversion from .eps to .pdf graphic files; run MikTeX as "latex --enable-write18"
\usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfinfo{
/CreationDate (D:20180802110000) % date format is year(4) month(2) day(2) hour(2) minute(2) second(2)
/ModDate      (D:\pdfdate)
 }
\hypersetup{
pdftitle    = {thesis title},
pdfsubject  = {thesis subject},
pdfauthor   = {your name},
pdfkeywords = {},
colorlinks  = {true},
linkcolor   = {black},
citecolor   = {black},
urlcolor    = {black}
}
\fi
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literaturverzeichnis}   % new name for the bibiography
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abbildung}           % new name for the figure
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis} % new name for the list of figures


\title{Minimal Example}
\subtitle{Thesis}
\author{from\\
Author\\ }
\date{\today}
\publishers{Advisors:\\
Dr. Ad, Visor1\\
Dr. Ad, Visor2
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
This is just a test \cite{mack2002}.
\appendix
\nocite{*}  % use all bibliography entries
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And my main.bib file looks like this and is in the same folder as the main.tex file.

```
@BOOK{mack2002,
title = {Schadensversicherungsmathematik},
publisher = {Verlag Versicherungswirtschaft},
year = {2002},
author = {Thomas Mack},
%  pages = {412},
% isbn = {3-540-29097-4},
volume{2},
language={english},
hyphenation={english}
}
```

on top I have some

```
 \include{./Chapter1/chapter1}
```

For those no aux file are created as well.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your `.bib` entry `volume{2},` should be `volume={2},`. You should not need both `\addbibresource{main}` and `\bibliography{main} `, one of `\addbibresource` or `\bibliography` is enough. Note that `\addbibresource` is the preferred command now, but that it needs the file name with extension, so `\addbibresource{main.bib}` would be best. If I change these two things the file compiles fine for me. How do you compile it? Can you compile a simple hello world example and get an `.aux` file? Can you show us the complete `.log` file (upload to pastebin or the like).

Comment: Look in the log-file if there are errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I can compile a simple Hello World but I do not get a aux file nor a log file.

Comment: I just opened the command window an checked the Errors, warnings, badboxes section and I found this error:

'main.tex 87 LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 87.'
It seems as the main file does not recognize the bibliography. But it is in the same folder.

Comment: Maybe you did not run Biber (or you ran BibTeX instead), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. But if you don't get a `.log` or `.aux` file from compiling that means something is going on. Either your build system deletes the temporary files, it moves them somewhere else, or it really does not create one (the last option is unlikely). All of that could be a problem when you want to run Biber. If your editor shows warnings and errors, something log-like is produced, you just have to get hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one error in your given bib file. Please correct the line

```
volume{2},
```

to correct

```
volume = {2},
```

Then you need to run biber to get your bibliography, because biber is standard if you do not use option `backend=bibtex,`.

Then you need to add the extention `.bib` in command

```
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

(command `\bibliography` is depreciated).

At last there are a lot of warnings because you are using an outdated version of KOMA-Script.

In the following MWE I corrected the error and most of the warnings:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics",
}
@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics},
}
@BOOK{mack2002,
title = {Schadensversicherungsmathematik},
publisher = {Verlag Versicherungswirtschaft},
year = {2002},
author = {Thomas Mack},
volume = {2},
language={english},
hyphenation={english},
}
\end{filecontents}


% kate: encoding iso-8859-1
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % Improves appearance of some cm-super fonts
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}    % warns about some obsolete latex  constructs
\documentclass[
12pt,                % font size 12pt
a4paper,             % layout for DIN A4
twoside,             % layout for one sided printing
headinclude,         % include head in layout computation
headsepline,         % horizontal line below head
BCOR=20mm,            % correction for fixation <=============================================
DIV=16,               % DIV-value for creating the print space, (see scrguien.pdf) <==========
parskip=half, version=first,         % spacing between paragraphs <===========================
openany,             % chapters may start on even and odd pages
bibliography=totoc,            % put bibliography into table of contents <=====================
numbers=noenddot,    % chapter numbers without full stop <=====================================
captions=tableheading,   % use table headings with correct spacing <===========================
]{scrbook}[2007/12/24]  % scrbook-Version min. v2.98 from 2007/12/24

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    % change to your encoding (e.g. utf8)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % correct pdf output (correct umlaut charaters)
%\usepackage{lmodern}             % fonts for pdf-file creation (use Type1 instead of Type3) - only needed, if cmsuper is not installed
%                                 % check the resulting pdf-file: fonts should been embedded, subsetted and of type 1 (NOT type 3!)
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}  % place the subscripts and superscripts in the right position
\usepackage{amsfonts}            % additional fonts like \mathbb, \mathfrak
\usepackage{amssymb}             % additional symbols
\usepackage{bbm}                 % indicator function
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{url}                 % support for urls
\usepackage[%
  style=alphabetic, 
  natbib=true,
  backend=biber, % <====================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <=======================================
%\bibliography{main} % <================================================
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage[english]{babel}             % English orthography
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}            % head and foot layout <=======
\usepackage{ushort}              % complex values require an underline (use\ushort or \ushortw)
\usepackage{units}               % package for setting units in a typographically correct way (e.g. \unit[3]{cm})
\usepackage{booktabs}            % package provides additional commands to enhance the quality of tables
\usepackage{datetime}            % provides \pdfdate command
\usepackage[pageno, draft]{listofsymbols}   % includes a lis of symbols/ good to have an overview over one's notations
\usepackage{verbatim}   % use multiline comments
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{subfig}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % amsmath: numbering equations

\usepackage{csquotes}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}          % enable scrheadings layout for head and foot

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
% non pdflatex settings (normal latex compiler assumed)
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\else
% different settings for the pdflatex compiler
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}           % enables automatic conversion from .eps to .pdf graphic files; run MikTeX as "latex --enable-write18"
\usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfinfo{
/CreationDate (D:20180802110000) % date format is year(4) month(2) day(2) hour(2) minute(2) second(2)
/ModDate      (D:\pdfdate)
 }
\hypersetup{
pdftitle    = {thesis title},
pdfsubject  = {thesis subject},
pdfauthor   = {your name},
pdfkeywords = {},
colorlinks  = {true},
linkcolor   = {black},
citecolor   = {black},
urlcolor    = {black}
}
\fi
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literaturverzeichnis}   % new name for the bibiography
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abbildung}           % new name for the figure
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis} % new name for the list of figures


\title{Minimal Example}
\subtitle{Thesis}
\author{from\\
Author\\ }
\date{\today}
\publishers{Advisors:\\
Dr. Ad, Visor1\\
Dr. Ad, Visor2
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
This is just a test \cite{mack2002}.
\appendix
\nocite{*}  % use all bibliography entries
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

results in the wished bibliography:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was the backend = biber thing.